# Calculate time difference according to if condition with Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time

I need to calculate the time difference between two specific rows in my dataframe.

if `Payload` column is `[1]->[0]` then I need to calculate the time difference between this row and the row after it if it set to `[0]->[1]`

this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({'Time':['12/01/2019 17:01:10', '12/01/2019 13:23:00', '12/01/2019 11:23:00', '12/01/2019 10:01:10','12/01/2019 09:01:10','12/01/2019 09:01:10'],
 'Payload':['[0]->[1]', '[0]->[1]','[1]->[0]','[0]->[1]','[1]->[0]','[0]->[1]']})
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
print('df\n',df)
for i in range (len(df)-1):
    if ((df['Payload'].iloc[i]=='[1]->[0]') & (df['Payload'].iloc[i+1]=='[0]->[1]')):
        df['diff']=df['Time'].iloc[i+1] - df['Time'].iloc[i]
        print(df['diff'])
```

**the calculations must done between these two rows:**

```
2 2019-01-12 11:23:00  [1]->[0]
3 2019-01-12 10:01:10  [0]->[1]
```

and these two rows:

```
4 2019-01-12 09:01:10  [1]->[0]
5 2019-01-12 09:01:10  [0]->[1]
```

but my code failed to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original dataframe has no column `diff`, and so when you call it in your loop it is created and constantly replaced by a single value.
What I would do is create an empty list prior to the loop, fill it, then add it to your dataframe.

```py
diff = []
for i in range(len(df) - 1):
    if df.iloc[i, 1] == '[1]->[0]' and df.iloc[i + 1, 1] == '[0]->[1]':
        time_diff = df.iloc[i + 1, 0] - df.iloc[i, 0]
    else:
        time_diff = 0
    diff.append(time_diff)

diff.append(0) # to fill the last value
df['Difference'] = diff
```